# Store CSS or HTML in localStorage

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I have this function to toggle a dark mode on and of with a single button.
It checks if the dark.css stylesheet is already added to the site, if yes it removes it. If there isn't a dark.css it loads it and appends it to the head.

Now I want to store this information in the localStorage so the browser remembers whether the dark.css should be loaded or not.

```
$(function() {
$('#toggler').click(function(){
    if ($('link[href*="css/dark.css"]').length) {
        $('link[href*="css/dark.css"]').remove();
    }
    else {
        var lightMode = document.createElement('link');
        darkMode.rel="stylesheet";
        darkMode.href="css/dark.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(darkMode);
    }
});
})
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Where is the localStorage you tried to store your value?

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('IsDarkTheme', 'true');` and `localStorage.getItem('IsDarkTheme')`

Comment: I know ho to set and get the item but I don't where to put those in the code

Comment: Also keep in mind that localStorage is not always accessible (private browsing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is check localStorage in your jQuery function. Preferably earlier in the function (so DOM is updated quickly in case you have some intensive code elsewhere), though not required.

```
$( function () {

  function appendDarkMode() {

    var darkMode = document.createElement( 'link' );

    darkMode.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    darkMode.href = 'css/dark.css';

    document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ].appendChild( darkMode );

  }

  // This is run when page is first loaded.
  if ( localStorage ) {

    var useDarkMode = localStorage.getItem( 'useDarkMode' );

    // The boolean we set in the click handler will become a string.
    useDarkMode === 'true' ? appendDarkMode() : localStorage.setItem( 'useDarkMode', false );

  }

  // Theme click handler.    
  $( '.toggler' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {

    var $darkModeLink = $( 'link[href*="css/dark.css"]' );

    $darkModeLink.length ? $darkModeLink.remove() : appendDarkMode();

    if ( localStorage ) {

      // Note that we're inverting the value here. By the time this
      // is run, we will have changed whether or not `dark.css` is
      // on the page. Which is opposite the initial value of
      // `$darkModeLink`.
      localStorage.setItem( 'useDarkMode', !$darkModeLink.length  );

    }

  } );

} );
```

Comment: The function itself works, but it doesn't switch back and forth, only changes the stylesheet once and also the item is not saved when reloading the page.

Comment: Just noticed a small error in the click handler. The logic was intended to check against the existence of the link element, but what it was actually doing was evaluating the existence of a jQuery object. Which we'll always get, even if no elements are found. Code updated. The localStorage value check has also been fixed to check against a string.

Comment: Thanks, the function works very well now except the localStorage doesn't remember its state so it is reset every time the page is reloaded.

Comment: Make sure that the name is the same for the localStorage item, using the same case etc. One of my previous versions of code had a space at the end of the name, make sure yours does not have that. Otherwise, it should work.

Comment: Coming back a month later I fully understand what you did and got it working. Thansk a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think your approach is the best (loading this way could produce a 'flash' of improperly styled content depending on where you put your JS logic), here's my solution (not tested, but should work):

FYI: You'll want to check for `localStorage` availability or roll a pollyfill. See [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

```
$(function() {
  var themes = {
    light: 'light',
    dark: 'dark'
  };

  var currentTheme = themes.light; // default to light

  function changeTheme(theme) {
    if (!theme || !themes[theme]) return;
    setTheme(theme);

    Object.keys(themes).forEach(function(t) {
      var linkEl = $('link[href*="css/' + t + '.css"]');
      if (linkEl.length && t !== theme) {
        linkEl.remove();
      }
    });
  }

  function setTheme(theme) {
    if (!theme || !themes[theme]) return;

    var linkEl = document.createElement('link');
    linkEl.rel="stylesheet";
    linkEl.href="css/" + theme + ".css";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(linkEl);

    if (localStorage) {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
    }

    currentTheme = theme;
  }

  if (localStorage) {
    var theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    changeTheme(theme);
  } else {
    changeTheme(currentTheme);
  }

  $('#toggler').click(function(){
      switch (currentTheme) {
        case themes.light:
          changeTheme(themes.dark);
          break;
        case themes.dark:
        default:
          changeTheme(themes.light);
          break;
      }
  });
})
```

Comment: The code tries to load a null.css why obviously isn't found

Comment: @DeeKoul good catch - Updated answer for null/undefined check.

Comment: Thanks, errors are gone but the toggler doenst do anything when clicking it. Could you provide me with a fix with with this fiddle?
https://jsfiddle.net/jrwjd7js/

Comment: @DeeKoul Sorry about that - I forgot I refactored to use an object instead of array for the themes and I needed to update the iterator and accessors. https://jsfiddle.net/jrwjd7js/6/  Answer updated as well

Comment: It still won't work for me. Are there any changes I have to do to your code? When the toggler is clicked, no css file is added to the header.

Comment: @DeeKoul you need to make sure you are referencing the correct relative CSS paths. On the JsFiddle it works perfectly. If you console log when clicking the toggle you’ll see the files trying to load, but obviously the CSS files don’t exist so it won’t actually load.

Comment: Just a detail, yet the check on localStorage is flawed, since in private mode the object is there yet one gets an error on settings items only. Furthermore the quota could be reached at any time. The only way to actually check it is a try-catch with a test item.

Comment: @Lain yes, however that seems a bit outside the scope of this question. Though I do agree a try/catch block would be ideal

Comment: It finaly works, thank you so much! I had to load the script in the head and not footer.